# How do I reset ios simulator in the given image back to original even after any number of rotations? Basically how to reset it back to normal

Tags: macos, mac, xcode-simulator

rotated simulator which has to be reset to normal. If it is in normal state then it turns left or right after my code gets called. How do i write an applescript to always reset it.

Below is my code for rotating it:

```
tell application "System Events"
      if menu bar item "Hardware" of menu bar 1 of application process "Simulator" exists then
        click menu item "Rotate Left" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Hardware" of menu bar 1 of application process "Simulator"
      else
        click menu item "Rotate Left" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Device" of menu bar 1 of application process "Simulator"
      end if
    end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, using **Script Editor**, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me to reorient the **Simulator** *window* in the *normal* view:

```applescript
tell application "Simulator" to activate

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click menu item "Portrait" of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu item "Orientation" of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu bar item "Device" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Simulator"
```